# why google chrome devtools application did not show the local storage but the plugin Storage Area Explorer shows

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have installed the [Storage Area Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TYMg.png) plugin into my google chrom browser. In the plugin in can see the local storage key value pair, but in the google chrome application could not show the local storage key value pair with the same url, why did this happen? this is the plugin that show values:

[image]

this is the application tab that did not show the values:

[image]

is it make them keep the same? both show the local storage values.

Comment: chrome.storage is not window.localStorage, which is shown by devtools.

Comment: The devtools application storage is window.localstorage? @wOxxOm

Comment: This is what I said.

Comment: Ok, I know. I have tested what you saied. That's right. I always think the storage is only one in google chrome. thank you for telling me this.@wOxxOm

Comment: The documentation for extensions is confusing. It calls chrome.storage.local a `Local Storage` the same name as DOM localStorage.

Comment: I think they should emphasize the difference in the document. @wOxxOm

Comment: But since no one reads past the name, they ended up confusing everyone :-)